# How to aggregate either unique string value or NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions

Is there a way to aggregate a string value if it is unique or otherwise return NULL. For example, given the table "STUFF":

```
Col_A | Col_B | Col_C | Col_D
    1 | Foo   | Bar   |     6
    2 | Foo   | NoBar |     0
    2 | Foo   | Foo   |     4
    1 | Foo   | Bar   |     6
```

So that this SQL

```
SELECT SUM(COL_A), STR_AGG_FUNC(COL_B), STR_AGG_FUNC(COL_C),SUM(COL_D) FROM STUFF
```

Would return:

```
Col_A | Col_B | Col_C | Col_D
    6 | Foo   | NULL  |    16
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this with max and a case statement on those columns.

```
select
   Col_A = sum(Col_A)
   ,Col_B = case when max(Col_B) = min(Col_B) then max(Col_B) else null end
   ,Col_C = case when max(Col_C) = min(Col_C) then max(Col_C) else null end
   ,Col_D = sum(Col_D)
From
   Stuff
```

Comment: Is there a performance penalty to this approach because of the inherent type conversion? In production, my table is quite large.

Comment: There's no real inherent type conversion here. It just using the case-sensitive order of the column to return the first / last. It's the same way order by orders a varchar column. `b` come before `A` simply based on their unicode values (or similarly the ASCII decimal or Hex or Oct order). However, aggregate functions can be taxing in general. indexes obviously play a factor in max / min.